# Laravel eloquent mutators not work on update data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have in my model accessors and mutators for hash/rehash data in database table fields. For example:

```
public function setFullNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['full_name'] = Helper::geted('encrypt', $value);
}

public function getFullNameAttribute($value)
{
    return Helper::geted('decrypt', $value);
}
```

When I'll save data to database all sending datas saving in hashed form but on update data not hashed. My save/update code:

```
$profile = [
    'full_name' => "John",
    'address' => "United Kingdom"
];

$profile_save = new Profile($profile);
$exist = Personal::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();
if($exist == 0) $user->profile()->save($profile_save);
if($exist == 1) $user->profile()->update($profile);
```

When I **first time** save this info to db:

[image]

When I **second time** enter to current URL data will be updated:

[image]
Why does not the information be stored in an encrypted form when updating information?

Comment: post your ```Helper::geted('decrypt', $value);```

Comment: dd($profile); (prior to update) - is the posted data encrypted at that point?

Comment: I updated my question. You can see detailed info on pictures.

Comment: `updateOrCreate()` looks like a better choice for your situation.

Comment: `updateOrCreate()` save duplicate rows on refresh page or on enter to current testing url. @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$user->profile()->update($profile);
```

Mutators and accessors work on eloquent and not on Query Builders. You are using update function which is a query builder function, so you are updating your database directly.
Use this:

```
$profile = [
    'full_name' => "John",
    'address' => "United Kingdom"
];
$profile = auth()->user()->profile;
if ($profile) {
    $profile->full_name = $profile['full_name'];
    $profile->address = $profile['address'];
    $profile->save();
} else {
    auth()->user()->profile()->create($profile);
}
```

Comment: How I can update then user profile without query builders?

Answer (score 10):

For anybody who has the same problem:

Just omitting the parantheses also does the trick, as this uses Eloquent instead of the Query Builder:

```
$user->profile->update($profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$instance->fill($request->all());
$instance->save();
```

*dont work
$instance->update($request->all());*